# Seat booking on flight QR4993 from Dohar to Kuala Lumpur (operated by Malaysia Airlines) on 3 May 2023

Tags: seating, qatar-airways

I am flying from Paris CDG to Kuala Lumpur leaving on the 2 May 2023 via Dohar. I have been able to reserve my seats on the flights operated by Qatar but not the flight operated by MAS.
Could you please tell me how I can reserve and pay for my seat on flight QR4993 departing Dohar at 0805 on 3 May 2023?

Comment: Have you [contacted Malaysia Airlines](https://www.malaysiaairlines.com/us/en/askmh.html) and asked?

Comment: How did you book these flights. Single booking or separate tickets?

Comment: Check MAS website, usually you can check your ticket and make some changes (according to the fare of your ticket). It may be possible that the seats cannot yet booked (some airline open some flights later: maybe they are not yet sure which aircraft to use (maybe a larger one, or a smaller one).